# Is there a way to add a callout label to a point in a chart, without using select?

Tags: vba, excel, charts

Is there a way to add a callout label to a point in a chart, without using `Select`?

Recording a macro, I got this:

```
Sub Macro9()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("SPC").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(4).Select
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCallout)
End Sub
```

But I would rather like to avoid using `Select`. I tried simply using the `SetElement`-method on the point, but that failed. Using the [`HasDataLabel = True`-method](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/914813) simply adds a datalabel.

Is there any workarounds to selecting the point and then using `SetElement` on the chart, or will I have to settle for something resembling the above macro?

Comment: Doesn't look to be possible, the `.SetElement` function can't be applied to the `Point` object for some reason. You can set pretty much all other `DataLabel` properties but not the Callout property without selecting.

Comment: Nevermind, an [`Item`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj227803.aspx) returns a series object, which is not a [points object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835907.aspx). But I think you can use an item on a points object. Will that take a `setelement`?

Comment: You want to add callout to only 1 point (or any given number of points, but not all points)?

Comment: @vegard Any given number of points, but not all points. On an arbitrary chart.

Comment: I can't find any *direct* way of doing it... but if you are not opposed to some dirty code, it should be possible to work around it. It's a relatively large amount of code for such a "small" undertaking, but if you are committed to avoiding `Select`, we can add an invisible series with only one point on top of the existing one (in the chart), which means that you can do `SetElement` on that particular series.

Comment: In that case, I think I would prefer using something more akin to the method described in the original question, as I am concerned that adding an extra series for each callout will quickly bloat the size of the chart. However I'd encourage you to post your solution with a small  explanation in the answers section, as it technically would be a correct answer to my question, and thus eligible for the bounty. @Vegard

Comment: One more question - does the chart need to have datalabels in general? That is to say, do you need datalabels on the points that aren't supposed to have callout?

Comment: @Vegard There is a datalabel on one of the points of the graph currently, yes.

Answer (score 9):

Is this what you are trying? In the below code we have avoided `.Activate/.Select` completely :)

Feel free to play with `.AutoShapeType` property. You can also format the data label to show the values in whatever format you want.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim objC As ChartObject, chrt As Chart, dl As DataLabel
    Dim p As Point

    Set objC = Sheet1.ChartObjects(1)
    Set chrt = objC.Chart
    Set p = chrt.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(4)

    p.HasDataLabel = True

    Set dl = p.DataLabel

    With dl
        .Position = xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd
        .Format.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangularCallout
        .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: That seems really close, and it also taught me that a callout-label is a sort of datalabel - for some reason I had the impression that they were two distinct objects :P

Comment: Yes, a data label is a shape next to a data point. Normally it is a textbox with no border and no fill. You can right-click on a label, though, and change the shape to any AutoShape. And a "callout" is a data label that uses one of the callout AutoShapes.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in a comment: I couldn't find a way to do this directly but thought I'd be able to work around it.

Turns out I was unsuccessful!

But let's cover an edge case which for some uses will have a pretty easy solution; say you don't need datalabels *except* for the instances where you want callout:

```
Sub chartTest()
    Dim co As ChartObject
    Dim ch As Chart
    Dim i As Integer

    ' The point index we want shown
    i = 2

    Set co = Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(2)
    Set ch = co.Chart

    co.Activate
    ch.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCallout)

    For j = 1 To s.Points.Count
        ' We can change this to an array check if we want several 
        '  but not all points to have callout
        If j <> i Then s.Points(j).HasDataLabel = False
    Next j
End Sub
```

For anyone desperate, the closest I came was to create an overlay using the original chart as a template. It doesn't work accurately for arbitrary charts, however, due to positioning issues with the callout box.

But at this point, you might as well have just added a textbox or something far less involved than copying a chart, deleting half its contents and making the rest of it invisible...

But for the sake of Cthul-- I mean, science:

```
Sub pTest()
    Dim co As ChartObject
    Dim ch As Chart
    Dim s As Series
    Dim p As Point

    Set co = Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1)
    Set ch = co.Chart
    Set s = ch.SeriesCollection(1)
    i = 2
    Call copyChartTest(co, ch, i)
End Sub

Sub copyChartTest(ByRef co As ChartObject, ByRef cht As Chart, ByVal i As Integer)
    Dim ch As Chart ' The overlay chart
    Set ch = co.Duplicate.Chart

    ' Set callout
    ch.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCallout)

    ' Invisibil-ate!
    With ch
        .ChartArea.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Visible = False
        .ChartTitle.Delete
        .Legend.Delete
    For j = 1 To .SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
        .SeriesCollection(1).Points(j).Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        If j <> i Then .SeriesCollection(1).Points(j).HasDataLabel = False
    Next j
    End With

    ' Align the charts
    With ch
        .Parent.Top = cht.Parent.Top
        .Parent.Left = cht.Parent.Left
    End With
End Sub
```

And the result: DataLabels intact with only 1 point having callout.

[image]

Comment: Looks really good, and it was interesting reading through your code figuring out how you did things. However, I am afraid that at the moment Siddhart's solution looks like the better one, so it seems likely he'll get the bounty. Gave you an upvote though :P

Comment: Not a problem - it is indeed a better solution. I wasn't really sniping for the bounty. I recognized your name from when I first started out on SO, and you were a big help on what at the time was a difficult project for me (and probably a bit off-topic as well). Since then I'd done a lot with VBA, so I figured I can at least offer some effort!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this free tool http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm by Rob Bovey?

There is an option "manual label" which seems to be very close to what you want. I am using the version of 1996-97 which has visible VBA code. I have not checked if the latest version has.

Comment: I can confirm that you can view the VBA code as it is visible in the download file of the provided link.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
Sub Macro9()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("SPC").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(4).HasDataLabel = True
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(4).DataLabel.Text = "Point 4 Test"
End Sub
```