# How to use pattern property in data-label C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am trying give shape to excel [**data label**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-format-of-data-labels-in-a-chart-ee7525e3-3a58-4142-b0e3-8140a1d6545e) using C#. But I din't know about [**FillFormat.Pattern**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/fillformat-pattern-property-excel).

Can anybody please help me, how to use it and give shape to Excel data label. 
Your help will be appreciated.

This is what I have done so far.

```
System.Collections.IEnumerator iEChartSeries = seriesCollection.GetEnumerator();
if(iEChartSeries.MoveNext()){
    var oSeries = (Excel.Series)(iEChartSeries.Current);
    Excel.Points pts = (Excel.Points) oSeries.Points(Type.Missing);
    System.Collections.IEnumerator iPoints = pts.GetEnumerator();
    while(iPoints.MoveNext())
    {
        var pt = (Excel.Point)(iPoints.Current);
        pt.HasDataLabel = true;
        pt.DataLabel.Position = Excel.XlDataLabelPosition.xlLabelPositionAbove;

        pt.DataLabel.Font.Name = "Arial";
        pt.DataLabel.Font.FontStyle = "Bold";
        pt.DataLabel.Font.Size = 8;   
        pt.DataLabel.Text = "N";
        pt.DataLabel.Format.Fill.Patterned = ??;// how to get circle/ triangle/ square shapes
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is a C# question, there is no need to include the VBA or Excel-VBA tags.

Comment: @braX done. Thnaks :)

Comment: @braX- agree this isn't Excel VBA code - but OP is asking about properties in the Excel object model normally accessed via VBA so the tag is, to a degree, relevant to the question.

Comment: So per your link to - http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/05/05/change-data-labels-in-charts/ - are you looking to include an up or down arrow and a % ? So the label would be like `N | 3%` - imagine pipe is the arrow...

Comment: No @RobinMackenzie I want to add shape around it. like this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-format-of-data-labels-in-a-chart-ee7525e3-3a58-4142-b0e3-8140a1d6545e#__toc319053765

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the automation for this [UI method](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-format-of-data-labels-in-a-chart-ee7525e3-3a58-4142-b0e3-8140a1d6545e#__toc319053765) is achieved with the `AutoShapeType` property, not `Fill`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153972/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-callout-label-to-a-point-in-a-chart-without-using-selec) and read the answer that won the bounty by @SiddharthRout.

For your code, replace this line:

```
pt.DataLabel.Format.Fill.Patterned = ??
```

With

```
pt.DataLabel.Format.AutoShapeType = 105;
```

105 is `msoShapeRectangularCallout`. I note from your comment on the other answer that you may not have a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Core` namespace where the [enumeration lives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms250864). The magic numbers are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432469(v=office.12).aspx).

HTH

Answer (score 1):

`Patterned` is a method to which you'll pass the pattern you wish. It's is used to set the ReadOnly property `.Pattern`

The syntax should be according to Patterned method as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.fillformat.patterned.aspx):

`pt.DataLabel.Format.Fill.Patterned( msoPatternZigZag );`

The different options to pass are listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms251188)

Comment: it it saying Error `The name 'msoPatternZigZag' does not exist in the current contex`

Comment: Add the namespace the `msoPatternType` resides in: `Microsoft.Office.Core`